# query under importrange not working

Tags: spreadsheet

Hi I am new to `google` spreadsheet. I have open a spreadsheet name `PMS` having various `shees` in it. one of its sheet name is `Overview`, already formulated and gathering data from rest other sheets.

I want to extract few columns to another spreadsheet, used `query(IMPORTRANGE("1yZSHctc0nCSy6Y0otufg0IXrlQXHyDBUqOEWpQ4dK94","overview!A4:M1000"),select Col1,Col2,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col12,Col13 where Col13=''",1)`

But it gives me only headers. when i reduce the range to `overview!A4:M34` it works and give me accurate data. I checked my overview sheet.. on row no. 35-40 column M is not ' ' and it is again blank from 41 - 80..

Please help me to tell why it is not giving data from entire sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Are there numerical values in column M?  If so, try this amended formula:

`query(IMPORTRANGE("1yZSHctc0nCSy6Y0otufg0IXrlQXHyDBUqOEWpQ4dK94","overview!A4:M1000"),"select Col1,Col2,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col12,Col13 where Col13 is null",1)`

The ='' is for text values, whereas 'is null' is used for numbers.